# Simultaneously Play & Save Movie

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avplayer

So right now my AVPlayer plays videos from remote URLs (video file sizes are 200-300KB) with the following code,

```
        AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:someURL options:nil];
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        cell.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];


        AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.player];
        cell.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

        layer.frame = someFrame;
        [cell.layer addSublayer: layer];
```

So far, I've only seen examples where videos are played just from the remote URL or they are downloaded first, and then played from the local URL.

I'd like to start playing the video from the URL, and **while it is playing**, I'd like to **save it locally to the cache**. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same to save the user some bandwidth, did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up having to download the video first, and then play it once it is downloaded. Let me know if you find a way to do it simultaneously.

Comment: I've tried all I could find hoping that at least one of the answer might be working on iOS 7.1 but with no success. If you try using AVAssetReader instead, you'll get a more detailed error instead of the unknown one.